# Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Block’ in Either

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a function that works both with [Block] and [Ground].
To tho so, I declared that the function recieves [a] and an Int that works as a flag to hold the infrmation of which one of the lists I'm using each time the function is invoked.

```hs
printRow::[a]->Position->Int->[Picture]
printRow [] pos n = []
printRow (h:t) (x,y) n | n==0 = ((printTile (Right h) (x,y)):(printRow t (x+1,y) n))
                       | otherwise = ((printTile (Left h) (x,y)):(printRow t (x+1,y) n))

printTile::Either Block Ground->Position->Picture
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```sh
Gloss.hs:47:51: error:  
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Block’  
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by  
        the type signature for:  
          printRow :: forall a. [a] -> Position -> Int -> [Picture]  
        at Gloss.hs:44:11  
      Expected type: Either Block Ground  
        Actual type: Either a Ground  
    • In the first argument of ‘printTile’, namely ‘(Left h)’  
      In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely  
        ‘(printTile (Left h) (x, y))’  
      In the expression:  
        ((printTile (Left h) (x, y)) : (printRow t (x + 1, y) n))  
    • Relevant bindings include  
        t :: [a] (bound at Gloss.hs:46:13)  
        h :: a (bound at Gloss.hs:46:11)  
        printRow :: [a] -> Position -> Int -> [Picture]  
          (bound at Gloss.hs:45:1)
```

Comment: The problem is that you declare that `printRow`  can be called with a list of *any* type. But you then pass its first value to a function which expects it to be a `Block` specifically. In fact, the two guards pass it in ways that make `a` need to be both a `Block` value and a `Ground`, so you can't fix this by simply changing the type signature of `printRow`. Either the implementation is wrong, or the signature of `printTile` is.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I think your comment is sufficient for an answer

Comment: In fact, the `Int` argument (which really could have been a `Bool`) is unnecessary, as `printRow` should have type `[Either Block Ground] -> Position -> [Picture]`; you need only pass each element of the first argument directly to `printTile`. In fact, `printRow` is essentially just a variation of `map printTile`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Robin Zigmond, `printRow` can't be as general as you claim, since the value it passes to `printTile` must be of type `Either Block Ground`, not an arbitrary type `a`. Thus, the function type must be

```
printRow :: [Either Block Ground] -> Position -> Int -> [Picture]
```

Once you've made this this change, the `Int` argument (which should have been a `Bool` anyway) is no longer necessary.

```
printRow [] _ = []
printRow (h:t) (x,y) = printTile h (x, y) : printRow t (x+1,y)
```

Note, though, that this is nearly the pattern encapsulated by the `zipWith` function:

```
zipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y  : zipWith f xs ys
```

What you want to do is call `printTile` on a pair of values, one an `Either Block Ground`, the other an updated position. You can easily get an infinite list of positions to use with `[(x', y) | x' <- [x..]]`, so `printRow` simply becomes

```
printRow bgs (x,y) = zipWith printTile bgs [(x',y) | x' <- [x..]]
```

---

An alternate reading of the question might have

```
printRow :: Either [Board] [Ground] -> Position -> [Picture]
```

as the function you want to define, in which case

```
printRow bgs (x,y) = zipWith printTile (map which bgs) [(x',y) | x' <- [x..]]
    where which = case bgs of
              Right _ = Right
              Left _ = Left
```

would be the answer. (It seems like there must be a simpler way of writing this; I'm blanking, though.)